# Why does Windows 10 think that my WPF application is a game?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I have a line-of-business .NET Framework 4.x application written in WPF. When I start it, Windows 10 briefly shows the XBox game bar:

[image: Windows 10 game bar]

<sup>If you don't recognize the image: It [looked differently](https://google.com/search?q=windows+10+game+bar&tbm=isch) before the Windows 10 1903 update.</sup>

So, apparently, Windows 10 thinks that my application is a game. I think that's hilarious, but I'm afraid that my customers might disagree.

How does Windows determine whether an application is worthy of a game bar or not? And how can my .NET application tell Windows that it isn't a game?

Comment: @mjwills: That's it, my exe is called `Simulator.exe`, which apparently matches some game's name. Well done finding the dupe question! Thanks.